# Can't launch Minecraft in debugging mode VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, minecraft

i have a problem with the run client,./gradlew runClientwork but when i try using the one with debbug it instant crash when mc open. I use vscode with the java extention pack and i install forge mdk 1.20.4. (I just start java and mc modding)

Here is the config file for the debbug

```
  "type": "java",
  "name": "runClient",
  "request": "launch",
  "mainClass": "net.minecraftforge.bootstrap.ForgeBootstrap",
  "projectName": "Mod",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\run",
  "vmArgs": "-Dforge.logging.console.level\u003ddebug -Dforge.logging.markers\u003dREGISTRIES -Dforge.enabledGameTestNamespaces\u003dexamplemod -Dforge.enableGameTest\u003dtrue -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses\u003dsystem -XX:HeapDumpPath\u003dMojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump",
  "args": "--launchTarget forge_userdev_client --version MOD_DEV --assetIndex 12 --assetsDir C:\\Users\\conta\\.gradle\\caches\\forge_gradle\\assets --gameDir .",
  "env": {
    "MOD_CLASSES": "${workspaceFolder}\\build\\sourcesSets\\main",
    "MCP_MAPPINGS": "official_1.20.4"
  },
  "preLaunchTask": "prepareRunClientCompile"
```

and here is the log crash :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at net.minecraftforge.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:48)
        at net.minecraftforge.bootstrap.ForgeBootstrap.main(ForgeBootstrap.java:18)
Caused by: com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ParsingException: Invalid bare key: ${mod_id}
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml.TableParser.parseKey(TableParser.java:175)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml.TableParser.parseTableName(TableParser.java:111)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml.TomlParser.parse(TomlParser.java:51)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.toml.TomlParser.parse(TomlParser.java:37)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:113)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:219)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:202)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core@3.6.4/com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.file.WriteAsyncFileConfig.load(WriteAsyncFileConfig.java:138)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser.modsTomlParser(ModFileParser.java:43)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser.readModList(ModFileParser.java:30)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile.<init>(ModFile.java:71)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile.<init>(ModFile.java:60)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.AbstractModProvider.createMod(AbstractModProvider.java:52)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ClasspathLocator.scanMods(ClasspathLocator.java:75)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModDiscoverer.discoverMods(ModDiscoverer.java:80)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.beginModScan(FMLLoader.java:154)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/net.minecraftforge.fmlloader@1.20.4-49.0.30/net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.beginScanning(FMLServiceProvider.java:58)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.runScan(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:98)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$runScanningTransformationServices$7(TransformationServicesHandler.java:96)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1779)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.runScanningTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:98)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:49)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:86)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:73)
        at SECURE-BOOTSTRAP/cpw.mods.modlauncher@10.1.2/cpw.mods.modlauncher.BootstrapEntry.main(BootstrapEntry.java:17)
        at net.minecraftforge.bootstrap@2.0.0/net.minecraftforge.bootstrap.Bootstrap.moduleMain(Bootstrap.java:97)
        ... 6 more
```

I trie delete the `ddebug -Dforge.logging.marker` to launch not in debbug but same probleme

Comment: This is the important part of the error: `com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ParsingException: Invalid bare key: ${mod_id}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)